# Scoping -- Counter function works normally but not in custom package

Tags: r

I've got a counter function that I like to wrap around another function ("fun") to help keep track of how many times I've called it. I keep track of the calls by creating a new environment "counter.env" if it doesn't already exist and storing the count there.

```
counter <- function(fun) {
if (!exists("counter.env", envir = .GlobalEnv)) {
counter.env <<- new.env(parent = globalenv())
assign("i", 0, envir = counter.env)
}
function(...) {
local(i <- i+1, env = counter.env)
fun(...)
}
}
```

Also I have a function "get_calls" which is simply a call to get the count from the environment. I'd like it to run a 0 in case the user calls this before the actual function they're calling, for whatever reason they'd do this.

```
get_calls <- function() {
if (!exists("counter.env", envir = .GlobalEnv)) {
counter.env <<- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)
assign("i", 0, envir = counter.env)
}
get("i", envir = counter.env)
}
```

Finally lets say the function I'm wrapping is a function with its own argument, "fun(arg1)". So I wrap it.

```
count.and.call <- counter(fun)
```

And I call it like this:

```
count.and.call(arg1)
```

Immediately "counter.env" is created in my global environment and I can return the call with get_calls.

Now, *drum roll* When I put these functions in a package,  and I build the package, and run

```
count.and.call(arg1)
```

the counter.env is not created in the global env. and it shows

```
error in eval(quote(i <- i + 1), counter.env) : 
object 'counter.env' not found
```

My immediate concern is to fix my counter, which is probably something to do with the environment scoping.

However I am also not sure if I have used the best practices for my counter function, if so, could I get some advice?

Comment: Check out `demo("scoping")`

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is that your package should not meddle with the global environment. If you want to store state, create an environment for it in your package's namespace. You don't even have to specify the location yourself, it happens automatically by default.

In a source file:

```
counter.env <- new.env()

# this gets run every time your package is loaded
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname)
{
    counter.env$i <- 0
}

counter <- function(fun)
{
    # do stuff...
   counter.env$i <- counter.env$i + 1
}

reset_counter <- function()
{
    counter.env$i <- 0
}

# necessary if you want the user to see the counter and you don't export counter.env
get_counter <- function()
{
    counter.env$i
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way very R-ish way to do this is using closures.  For example:

```
countingFun <- function(fun) {
  count <- 0
  function(x) {
    count <<- count + 1
    fun(x)
  }
}

count <- function(fun) {
  environment(fun)$count
}
```

This keeps the count in the environment of the function, which is created automatically, containing all the variables that are local to the call to `countingFun`.  Then you can do

```
myMean <- countingFun(mean)
mySd   <- countingFun(sd)
myMean(x)
mySd(x)
myMean(x)
count(myMean)  # 2
count(mySd)    # 1
```

You might want to add some error checking to `count`, to make sure it isn't being called on a function that isn't being counted.